# Updating two fields of an observable collection item at once using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have two Observable Collection lists of the same type:

```
ObservableCollection<MyDataModel> source;
ObservableCollection<MyDataModel> target;
```

Suppose they are already populated, so I am trying to update target from source but only two fields and the first item that matches (I want to keep the rest of fields untouchable):

```
foreach (var s in source)
{
    target.First(t => t.Id == s.Id).Id = s.Id;
    target.First(t => t.Id == s.Id).Desc = s.Desc;
}
```

My model:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

In the above foreach I am repeating target.First twice and I would like to avoid this and to do it at once. Is it possible using Linq?

Comment: Why can't you just `var current = target.First(t => t.Id == s.Id);` and then do whatever you want with `current`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `First()` once and assign the result to a variable.

```
foreach (var s in source)
{
    var item = target.First(t => t.Id == s.Id);
    item.Id = s.Id;
    item.Desc = s.Desc;
}
```

Also, since your criteria to find the item is if the ids match, you don't really need the `item.Id = s.Id;` step.

### EDIT

However the above code run the risk of throwing an exception if the item was not found in target. This would be a better approach:

```
foreach (var s in source)
{
    var item = target.Where(t => t.Id == s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Id = s.Id;
        item.Desc = s.Desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh @Federico beat me to it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
foreach (var s in source)
{
    var t = target.First(x => x.Id == s.Id);
    t.Desc  = s.Desc;       
    t.Country = s.Country;
}
```

The simple answer is an O(source * target) operation. Performance can be improved to O(source + target) by using a dictionary:

```
var sourceDict = source.ToDictionary(s => s.Id);
foreach (var t in target)
{
    MyDataModel s;
    if (sourceDict.TryGetValue(t.Id, out s))
    {
        t.Desc = s.Desc;
        t.Country = s.Country;
    }
}
```